# Why matplotlib.pyplot gives me lots of lines instead of one in my figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am producing data and storing them in a numpy array. I am also calculating a variable and storing those variables in another array. They have different shapes and ndims but they are plottable since I tried it with another simple code with the same logic.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([0.05718623, 0.05446883, 0.04395619, 0.03004849])
b = np.array([[0.61745], [0.45825], [0.80061], [0.3719]])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I want to plot two arrays with my stored data with the following code:

```
works = [Data]
probability = [Data2]
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(probability, works)
```

I get this:

[image]

However when I place a 'bo' in the plt.plot() I get this:

```
works = [Data]
probability = [Data2]
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(probability, works, 'bo')
```

[image]

So I don't want blue spots. Instead of that I want a single curve like blue spots. What am I missing here? What is the problem behind this ? Or this question needs how I produce my data ?

PS: Data.ndim = (1000,) Data2.ndim = (1000,1)

Comment: Your data needs to be sorted on x

Comment: @JohanC with the sorting x-axis array it is still same

Comment: `probability, works = zip(*sorted(zip(probability, works)))`. Both lists need to be sorted together

Comment: @JohanC yes its correct. What is the logic here ?

Comment: plot will connect the first to the second to the third. If you don't sort the values, these lines can go very wild.   For zip-sorted-zip see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629253/what-does-the-code-zip-sorted-zipunits-errors-do)

Comment: `s = np.argsort(probability); plt.plot(probability[s], works[s])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.plot(probability, works)` connects all dotes with line segments in the order listed in the input array.

For example, `plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,4,9])` makes a nice piece-wise line connections between (1,1), (2,4) and (3, 9) in the given order. On the other hand, `plt.plot([1,3,2], [1,9,4])` would join (1,1) with (3, 9) with a line segment and (3, 9) and (2, 4) with a line segment -- we get an ugly plot in the later case.

As JohanC suggested, you need to sort the data. Sorting just the first array will ruin the correspondence: `Data[0]` corresponds to `Data2[0]`. Therefore, we need to sort `Data`, but keep the correspondence. `zip(Data, Data2)` freezes the correspondence. `sorted` sorts by the first index first in Python, i.e., it would sort Data. Finally, we need to undo `zip` and get back our two arrays.
`zip(*sorted(zip(Data, Data2))` does exactly that.